# Linq query not giving desired results

Tags: c#, linq, join, asp.net-core

I'm working to build a linq query that provides a single minimum value out. However, I keep getting the wrong minimum value. I'm certain it is a join issue but I can't get an outer join to work. I've tried some outer joins based on other posts but can't make anything work. I'm not sure which table I need to outer join to make this work. I think I've tried I think every combination I could.

Here's the query I started with:

```
(from r in Results
    join entry in Entries on r.EntryId equals entry.EntryId
    join entryEvent in EntryEvents on entry.EntryId equals entryEvent.EntryId
    join eswimmer in EntrySwimmers on entry.EntryId equals eswimmer.EntryId
    where eswimmer.SwimmerId == 12027 && entryEvent.EventNumberId == 1233
    select r.Time)
.Min();
```

An outer join attempt:

```
from r in Results
join en in Entries on r.EntryId equals en.EntryId
join ev in EntryEvents on en.EntryId equals ev.EntryId into evJoined
join s in EntrySwimmers on en.EntryId equals s.EntryId into sJoined
from ev in evJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
from s in sJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
where (s.SwimmerId == 12027 && ev.EventNumberId == 1233)
select r.Time;
```

The issue is that I'm getting the minimum value from all results for the swimmer rather than the minimum value for that swimmer AND the specific event.

The class structures look like this:

Results

```
public int ResultId
public int EntryId
public ICollection<Entry> Entry
public int EntryEventId
public ICollection<EntryEvent> EntryEvent
public TimeSpan Time
```

Entries

```
public int EntryId
public ICollection<EntrySwimmer> EntrySwimmers
public Result Results
public ICollection<EntryEvent> EntryEvents
```

EntryEvents

```
public int EntryEventId
public int EventNumberId
public EventNumber EventNumbers
public int EntryId
public Entry Entry
```

EntrySwimmers

```
public int EntryId
public Entry Entries
public int SwimmerId
public Swimmer Swimmers
```

I'm still learning about linq, joins, etc. so explanations are appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Write a working query in T-SQL first and then work backwards from there.

Comment: I'm getting the same results in SQL.

Comment: Is this model right? `Entry` has many `EntryEvents` *and* many `EntrySwimmers`. How are you ever going to link a swimmer to a specific `EntryEvent`?

Comment: Yes because an entry can be for an individual that registers for multiple events OR it can be a relay entry that has one event and multiple swimmers. I've tried using the navigation properties but can't seem to get results using them in this case for some reason. I've ended up using a join starting with the entryswimmer which seems to be working. I'll keep trying with the navigation properties though since I know I have to add more to this query in the very near future (like filtering for only past meet results for the current season).

Answer (score 0):

You already have the navigation properties mapped so basically you don't need any joins since your ORM will cover it for you:

```
var min = Results
            .Include(x => x.Entry.Select(y => y.EntrySwimmers)) //here you should rename Entry to Entries ideally in your result class  
            .Include(x => x.Entry.Select(y => y.EntryEvents))
            .Where(x => x.Entry.EntrySwimmers.Any(y => y.SwimmerId == 12027) && x.EntryEvents.Any(y => y.EventNumberId == 1233))              
            .Min(x => x.Time);
```

Not sure why you have Events both in Result and in Entry though.

Comment: I've tried what you have but keep getting a message that ICollection<Entry> does not contain a definition for EntrySwimmers and Result does not contain a definition for EntryEvents.

Comment: Then you should check your mappings to see what is wrong. You have to check your mappings are set exactly as DB e.g. one to one, one to many relationships

Comment: I modified the where clause to this: `Where(x => x.Entries.Any(y => y.EntrySwimmers.Any(e => e.SwimmerId == swimmerid))
                            && x.EntryEvent.Any(y => y.EventNumberId == eventid))` but I'm getting nothing but 00:00:00.00 as an output. I checked the mappings and they look ok to me. What should I look for specifically?

Comment: I reckon you should check the sql generated from the code to see what is wrong? maybe you should use entryevent on the entry rather than result